# Convert .mid to .wav using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, audio, wav, midi

I've been using this library (http://kenschutte.com/midi) to work with midi files and the functions on here have been very helpful. However, the `midi2audio()` method only produces garbled .wav files no matter what midi I put in (although the notes are recognizable and the correct midi is being played). Has anyone else used this function library and run into this same problem and if so, how could I fix this? Or is there another function I can use online somewhere that does the same thing?

Below is the code used to generate the .wav file (copied and pasted from the link above)

`[y,Fs] = midi2audio(midi);
% save to file:
% (normalize so as not clipped in writing to wav)
y = .95.*y./max(abs(y));
wavwrite(y, Fs, 'out.wav');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that midi2audio only include very rudimentary sound synthesis, with frequency modulated synthesis as default. If you change to simple sine wave synthesis maybe it will sound better?

```
[y,Fs] = midi2audio(midi, 'sine')
```

If that still doesn't cut it you'd probably want to use more sophisticated software instruments.

The simplest cross-platform method for this is probably [FluidSynth](http://www.fluidsynth.org) (also available through various repositories like MacPorts, Homebrew, apt-get, GitHub…)
FluidSynth uses sample based sound synthesis to translate the MIDI instructions into audio, and a sample bank in the SoundFont2 format is required for it to work. One such can be found [here](http://www.schristiancollins.com/generaluser.php).

Having sorted that out, all you have to do to make a WAVE file out of your MIDI file is to type this into your terminal/console:

```
fluidsynth -F out.wav path-to-fm2-file in.mid
```

Comment: Unforunately I tried to change the 'fm' parameter to 'sine' and the sound still wasn't of very high quality. Would I be able to run FluidSynth inside of MATLAB code somehow or would I just need to type the command you mentioned into the terminal?

Comment: @pdrum I'm not familiar with matlab, but chances are there is a way to invoke a system command from inside, and capture the output. But the easiest method, depending on your use, would probably to do it straight from the terminal (osx, linux) or console (windows).